# Please explain middle join in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I recently was asked for a question on sql about **middle join**?

I did got the job..however, could someone explain about middle join in sql for example with syntax and where it is used?

Thanks

Comment: There's no such thing......do your job right.

Comment: In interview, If you are asked which you have not heard about, admit it. Tell them I have not heard about it instead of telling them something wrong. No one knows each and everything about everything. By the way, there is no thing such as MIDDLE JOIN, it was a trick question.

Comment: i did told them that I haven't heard about it. I was still curious to know for future references. I felt it may be a new addition to sql/something like that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no such thing as "middle join". This is a trick interview question, as described in [this thread](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic432627-1151-1.aspx).

```
SELECT . . . FROM . . . SomeTable MIDDLE JOIN . . .
```

This is creating the alias `MIDDLE` for `SomeTable`. The most important thing to be aware of is that `MIDDLE` is not an SQL key word.